# Opengl application squeak noise

Tags: c, glfw

A simple opengl application makes a creaking sound.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On multiple machines? Or just on one test device? If the application is running uncapped (i.e. without vsync) then it can reach very high FPS and cause coil whine on some GPUs or even voltage spikes causing crackling out of speakers when the audio circuit is badly isolated.

Comment: @user5263478 You are not initilizing Glew or Glad Library before using opengl functions like glClear also try turning on the vertical sync property of your card , it can be done through code also  "glfwSwapInterval( 1 ); , it is due increased power consumption by the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is only  a specification it is up to the driver manufacturer to implement the specification to a driver that the specific graphics card supports.Developers need to retrieve the location of the functions and store them in function pointers.

Library's like glew or glad manages this task , so before calling any opengl function we need to initilize them.

The squeaking sound is due to increased power consumption of the card.
Enabling v-sync locks the framerate and thus reduces the GPU cycles, and lowers power consumption.

It can be either done from the property panel of the card or through code , in case of GLFW.

```
glfwSwapInterval( 1 )
```